# Select Rows based on Where Condition but group them based on a specific Column value

Tags: c#, sql

I want to Select some rows from the database based on my where clause and group them based on some condions.

I have done this till now

```
SELECT col1, Encounter.EncounterId, col2, col3 FROM Abcd
Where SomeCondition
GroupBy Encounter.EncounterId
```

Returns an error is:

> *not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause.*

Comment: Probably, you are selecting a column (`col2, col3`)which is not in you group by column list so it is giving that error. (Only MySQL support this thing)

Comment: You need to group all columns which are not using aggregate function

Comment: Should i Group all my columns ?? i have around 20 selected ??

Comment: you need to check that if you are getting desired result by adding those columns in group by list or not. if not then share sample data and expected output to understand what you actually need.

Comment: where is your aggregate function? If you want to `GROUP BY` a column and if order of the groups is not important, then you can use sorting (`ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 SELECT col1, Encounter.EncounterId, col2, col3 FROM Abcd
 Where SomeCondition
 GroupBy col1, Encounter.EncounterId, col2, col3
```

Comment: I want grouping to happen based on one column value not all my columns

Comment: But it is necessary to add all the column's in `Group By` if they are not in any aggregate function. You must to add it.